# MYSQL warning Invalid utf8 character string

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, type-conversion, iso-8859-1

I am trying to use below query to enforce UTF-8 encoding on a column data.

```
SELECT convert(binary convert(summary using latin1) using utf8) FROM blogs b;
```

The below warnings getting logged in mysql console

[image]

What are below character represent in the above warnings?
    `'AE2065','927320','927320','927320','F16120','C02070','AE2043','F16F6C','93426F','93426F','E4646F','E46E73','E46DE4','E47974','C02070','934355','934355'`

and how can I find out corresponding actual character symbols for above list?

Comment: I think you might need to have a look here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-cjk.html

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804883/how-to-find-non-utf-8-characters-in-mysql-database-and-remove-or-substitute -- Please do not post the same question twice.  Or is this supposed to be somehow different??

Comment: Thanks, I deleted duplicate question

Answer (score 2):

Well, given these source character sets, you get this text.  For example, several treat `AE` as `®`

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('AE2065') USING %s) USING utf8mb4):

cp1250, cp1251, cp1256, cp1257, geostd8, hebrew, latin1, latin5, latin7
                                            4  3 '® e'
                    cp850, cp852, keybcs2   4  3 '« e'
                                    cp866   4  3 'о e'
                                      hp8   4  3 'Û e'
                                   latin2   4  3 'Ž e'
                                    macce   4  3 'ģ e'
                                 macroman   4  3 'Æ e'
                                 armscii8   5  3 '… e'
                              cp932, sjis   5  3 'ｮ e'
                             koi8r, koi8u   5  3 '╝ e'
                                   tis620   5  3 'ฎ e'
```

For the `92`, a likely interpretation is `’`

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('927320') USING %s) USING utf8mb4)

                              cp932, sjis   4  2 '痴 '
                                    euckr   4  2 '뭩 '
                                      gbk   4  2 '抯 '
                                    cp850   4  3 'Æs '
                                    cp852   4  3 'ĺs '
                                    cp866   4  3 'Тs '
                                  keybcs2   4  3 'Žs '
                          macce, macroman   4  3 'ís '
cp1250, cp1251, cp1256, cp1257, geostd8, latin1
                                            5  3 '’s '
```

So far, I see that `latin1` is common.  I'll try another:

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('F16120') USING %s) USING utf8mb4)

                                     big5   4  2 '鎙 '
                                    cp932   4  2 ' '
                                      gbk   4  2 '馻 '
                                 armscii8   4  3 'րa '
cp1250, cp1257, dec8, latin1, latin2, latin5, latin7
                                            4  3 'ña '
                                   cp1251   4  3 'сa '
                           cp850, keybcs2   4  3 '±a '
                                    cp852   4  3 '˝a '
                                    cp866   4  3 'ёa '
                                    greek   4  3 'ρa '
                                   hebrew   4  3 'סa '
                                      hp8   4  3 'þa '
                             koi8r, koi8u   4  3 'Яa '
                                    macce   4  3 'Ůa '
                                 macroman   4  3 'Òa '
                                   tis620   5  3 '๑a '
```

Again, latin1 seems likely.

So,... What you need to do is declare that the bytes that you are feeding to MySQL are encoded in `latin1`.  Then they will be automatically converted to the declaration of the column, which should be `utf8` (or `utf8mb4` if you want Chinese and Emoji).

Since you seem to *already* have latin1 bytes in the table (in column `summary`), it is not a question of whether you have utf8 or not; you do *not* have utf8.  And the column is *not* declared utf8.

So, what do you really want do do??  Perhaps you want to `ALTER` the table to change the character set to utf8?  See

```
ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...
```

What you had was close:

```
CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(UNHEX('AE2065') USING latin1) USING utf8) --> Warning
CONVERT(       CONVERT(UNHEX('AE2065') USING latin1) USING utf8) --> '® e'
```

But, then what will you do with it?  If the column is latin1, and you stick the converted stuff back in, you will get "double encoding", making things worse.

Perhaps you also have utf8-encoded characters sitting in a latin1 column?  That's a mess -- "double encoding".

See [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) then further elaborate on your Question.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your data is stored as `latin-1` charset. You could convert it as following:

```
SELECT convert(cast(convert(summary using  latin1) as binary) using utf8) FROM blogs b;
```

Did you actually intend to store your data as `latin-1`? If you intend to store your `summary` as `UTF-8` you could update your table as follows:

```
UPDATE blogs SET 
    summary=convert(cast(convert(summary using  latin1) as binary) using utf8)
WHERE 1
```

Comment: Yes data is stored as latin1, but I want find out which characters causing above warning while doing above conversion.

Comment: The update statement truncating the data and some characters are replaced by question marks.